# Llamar ConsoleApp desde python

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x, terminal

Buenas. Mi problema es que estoy intentando llamar una aplicacion de consola(hecha en c#) desde python , y llama el proceso en la misma terminal. Por lo tanto no me devuelve la termianl para seguir tecleando y a su vez el exe de c# solo es para esuchar un comando y escribirlo en un documento txt. Como hago para llamar ese exe pero a otra terminal distinta? Utilizo el modulo subprocess de la stlib de python3. A su vez subprocess.Popen("ruta"). Agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Y si utilizas el modulo os digo hay un método llamado system para que puedas hacer cualquier llamado a la terminal y cualquier operacion
**os.system(codigo)#en string,si quieres ejecutar  muchos comandos  da espacios o saltos de linea 
**
Ahí te va un atajo que hice para ir directo a un directorio:

```
     def atajo():
        w = int(input("{a}Ingrese cuantas ventanas quiere{b}:  ".format(a = "<---",b= "-->")))
        a = "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\pythonxd"
        for i in range(w):
          os.system("start cd {}".format(a))

      atajo()
```